# Django renders an "in exception" page instead of a page that can help debugging

Tags: javascript, python, django, debugging, django-templates

Django was working normally, suddenly I wasn't able to get any debugging messages. I have been commenting out my code to see which part is causing that and it turned out to be my last_visit middleware which gets when was the last time user visited the app. But why? what is wrong with it?!

last_visit.py (The middleware I made)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class SetLastVisitMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).update(last_visit=now())
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        return HttpResponse("in exception")
```

settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'users.get_request.RequestMiddleware',
    'users.last_visit.SetLastVisitMiddleware'
]
```

Comment: How someone supposed to help you without seeing your actual code?

Comment: Ok I uploaded my settings.py and middlewares

Comment: I don't think this is enough... Please do create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can help you faster !!!

Comment: What Exactly Should I share?! I don't know even why that problem occured, I didn't change anything in my settings, i didn't install any weird packages and I don't think there is anything wrong with my middlewares, the problem suddenly appeared without me doing anything even! My app have been running for over 2 weeks in production and i didn't start to see this problem till two days ago. What piece of code should I exactly share? I will add my requirements.txt tho

Answer (score 1):

You see the detailed description of the error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. When it is changed to False, Django will display a standard page generated by the handler for that status code.
I think in your case, DEBUG is set to false. Try changing it to True.

Comment: It's set to True, and even if it was False it should give server Error 500 page instead of this page. Thanks for help